# SignalR the new message does not shows in target client's message box - Angular

Tags: angular, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I've created a chat system and now I'm trying to implement it by SignalR but the new message doesn't show in the target client's message box. It just happen after sending a new message to the server. However the new message and old messages shows correctly in the sender's browser

Here is my code:

```
baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
hubUrl = environment.hubUrl;
private hubConnection: HubConnection;
private messageThreadSource = new BehaviorSubject<Message[]>([]);
messageThread$ = this.messageThreadSource.asObservable();

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


createHubConnection(userToken: UserToken, otherUserId: string, skip: string) {
 this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
   .withUrl(this.hubUrl + 'message?targetUserId=' + otherUserId + '&&skip=' + skip, {
     accessTokenFactory: () => userToken.token
   })
 .withAutomaticReconnect()
 .build()

this.hubConnection
  .start()
  .catch(error => console.log("SignalR Message Error : ", error));

this.hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessageThread", messages => {
  this.messageThreadSource.next(messages);
});

this.hubConnection.on("NewMessage", message => {
  this.messageThread$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(messages => {
    this.messageThreadSource.next([...messages,message]);
  })
});


}
```

To explain more there is value in both `message` and `messages` in the `NewMessage` hub connection. Having said that if I only pass `message`, the target client's message box will become empty, I mean all the previous message eliminate from the HTML and at the same time only the latest message will show up in the sender client's message box.

```
this.messageThreadSource.next([message]);
```

Comment: what happens if you remove `take(1)` from `this.messageThread$.pipe(take(1))`?

Comment: @florencia-cames The new message shows repeatedly a million times :) in the sender's browser but nothing happened in the target's browser.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar implementation of code for another kind of data. But I still receive two updates, one for the initial, and another one with current changes.
What I do on my code i(i'll adapt your's to mine)

```
 this.hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessageThread", messages => {
  this.messageThreadSource.next(messages);
});

this.hubConnection.on("NewMessage", message => {
    this.messageThreadSource.next(message);
});
```

And on the subscription side I'll do something like this.

```
this.yourservice.messageThreadSource.subscribe((message: any) => {
      this.message = [...messages,message];
      //or
      this.message.concat(message)
});
```

The only difference is that I'm mergin the messages and messgge on the final ts document using the subscription not on the signal responses. And in this code i'm using `this.message` as a variable that will display all the messages on the html

Answer (score 0):

I would have the following aproach:

```js
public message: Message;
public messages: Message[] = [];

public startConnection = () => {
  this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl('https://localhost:5001/signalRHub')
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
  .withAutomaticReconnect()
  .build();

this.hubConnection
.start()
.then(() => {
    console.log('Connection started');
    this.addMessageListener();
})
.catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err))
 
// Add message to the chat
public newMessage(message: string) {
    this.hubConnection.invoke("NewMessage", message).catch((ex) => {
        console.log(ex);
    });
}

// Add chat message listener
private addMessageListener = () => {
    this.hubConnection.on('BroadcastMessage', (message: Message) => {
        this.message = message;
        this.messages.push(this.message);
        console.log(message);
    });
}
```

Comment: I used this approach, but there is still the same problem.

Comment: having said that when the message is logged in both sender and receiver browser console but it does not show in the receiver's chat box. It's really weird I really don't know what I should do.

Comment: No, it's not. Make sure that you can add first to a normal array as I have here `public messages: Message[] = [];` and then if this works, add the behaviour that you have with `BehaviorSubject`.